# Why are anonymous types in .NET implemented as reference type?

Tags: .net, linq, performance, anonymous-types, value-type

Because an anonymous type is readonly anyway, is would be more efficient if they implemented them as structs so that linq queries doesn't need to create tons of temporary objects:

```
// This doesn't make any sense, it is just for demonstration
var result = thingies
.Select(x=> new {A = 1, B = 2, C = 3});
```

Btw. I got this idea, when [reading this](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/scottallen/archive/2008/07/14/optimizing-linq-queries.aspx)

**EDIT:**

The greatest thing would be if the compiler would, depending on the size and usage of the variable (must if be passed to lots of methods), decide whether to make if a value type or reference type.

But could the following sentence which I found in the msdn cause problems then:

> If two or more anonymous types in the same assembly have the same
>   number and type of properties, in the same order, the compiler treats
>   them as the same type.

Since an anonymous object (with its associated type) cannot leave the method which it is defined in we have no problems here, do we?

Comment: I'm not sure how your sample code demonstrates anything... Still, it's an interesting question, +1

Comment: Implementing structs rather than classes tends to imply more copying, rather than less.

Comment: @Damien, yes, but reference types put more pressure on the GC

Comment: @Thomas - In most circumstances where anonymous types are being used, I'd expect them to end up inside heap allocated objects such as collections. They'll tend to put the same pressure on the GC as classes.

Comment: @Damien: But for an object you need to store the reference to it (4 byte). This is much if the object is small and there is only 1 reference to it at a given time. Also, an object has some bytes overhead to store meta information (IIRC an object is at least 12 bytes in size).

Comment: A very similar argument can be made for Tuple<>.  That's been discussed here and blogged about.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The pressure on the GC is largely proportional to the number of allocations, not the space allocated. Also, structs in an array provide better locality of reference than objects on the heap. MikeP's answer makes the answer that's actually valid I believe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The full .NET garbage collector is particularly well-optimized for two cases: large, long-lived objects that last significant amounts of time, and small, short-lived objects that die off quickly. Gen0 collections are practically free given how fast they are (so fast and frequent, in fact, that many profilers don't even bother showing them or their contents), so there's little reason to avoid temporaries that will be gone within the scope of the function that created them.

Anonymous types fit the second case almost perfectly; they're not meant to outlive the function that creates them (although you can do it with some trickery). Given this model, and given the fact that most value types are relatively expensive to copy around, and given that many LINQ queries involve a long chain of functions that would all require yet another copy, it makes sense to me that the designers chose to make them reference types.

Comment: I know memory allocations in .NET are relatively cheap, but according to http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/scottallen/archive/2008/07/14/optimizing-linq-queries.aspx, it isn't this isignificant.

Comment: Excellent answer to a tough question. Wish I could upvote more than once.

Answer (score 1):

If anonymous types were value types I'm sure I could make some benchmarks that showed how horrendous all the copying was and how they should be reference types so that they don't need to be copied everywhere.  There are benefits and tradeoffs to both approaches and the language designers chose to use reference types; I would suspect because reference types are more common, more easily understood, and work with more APIs than value types.

Utmost speed isn't the point of anonymous types though.  They are built for the 90% of developers doing reasonable sized LINQ queries who need an intermediate type for storing results.  For the 10% that require millions of objects I would suggest they create a concrete type and invest in some optimizing time.